# Interesting identity for the value of an integral involving complex-valued square root.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am looking for a simple proof of the following identity which holds by numerical tests:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{1-x^2-2i\gamma x}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{a}{1-x^2+2i\gamma x}
}\right)dx={i\pi a}\operatorname{sgn}\gamma,
$$
where $a$ and $\gamma$ are real numbers. The result suggests using the residue theorem, but the residues at singularities of the integrand seem to be zero...

Any hint or suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result depends on the choice of branch cut. Indeed, with the principal square root, the result is false if $a$ is negative with large modulus:

[image: comparison of the prediction and the actual value]

In this answer, we will prove a corrected version of OP's identity. To this end, define

$$ f(z) := 1+\frac{a}{1-z^2-2i\gamma z} \tag{1}. $$

This functions has poles at $z = -i\gamma \pm \sqrt{1-\gamma^2}$ and zeros at $z = -i\gamma \pm \sqrt{1+a-\gamma^2}$. Now if $a > -1$ and $\gamma > 0$, then all of these points lie in the lower half plane, and so, there exists a unique analytic function $g$ on the closed upper half plane $\overline{\mathbb{H}} = \{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Im}(z) \geq 0\}$ such that

$$ \lim_{\overline{\mathbb{H}} \ni z \to \infty} g(z) = 1
\qquad \text{and} \qquad
g(z)^2 = f(z). \tag{2} $$

Moreover, we can check that $g(x) = \sqrt{f(x)}$ holds for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, where $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is the principal square root. Now we claim

> **Proposition.** For each $a > -1$ and $\gamma > 0$, we have
>
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \left( \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{f(-x)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = i \pi a. \tag{3} $$

Note that this claim is enough to establish OP's identity for $a > -1$.

*Proof of Proposition.* Write $I$ for the left-hand side of $\text{(3)}$. Then

\begin{align*}
I
&= \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} x \left( \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{f(-x)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2 \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-R}^{R} x \left( \sqrt{f(x)} - 1 \right) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= 2 \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{-\Gamma_{R}} z \left( g(z) - 1 \right) \, \mathrm{d}z,
\end{align*}

where $-\Gamma_{R}$ is the clockwise-oriented upper semicircular contour from $-R$ to $R$. Parametrizing $-\Gamma_{R}$ by $z = Re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta$ from $\pi$ to $0$, we get

\begin{align*}
I
&= -2i \lim_{R\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} R^2e^{2i\theta} \left( g(Re^{i\theta}) - 1 \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta.
\end{align*}

But in view of $\text{(2)}$, it follows that

$$ R^2e^{2i\theta} \left( g(Re^{i\theta}) - 1 \right)
= \frac{R^2e^{2i\theta} \left( f(Re^{i\theta}) - 1 \right)}{g(Re^{i\theta}) + 1}
\xrightarrow[R\to\infty]{} -\frac{a}{2} $$

holds uniformly in $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. Therefore we can interchange the order of limit and integration to obtain

\begin{align*}
I
&= -2i \int_{0}^{\pi} \lim_{R\to\infty} R^2e^{2i\theta} \left( g(Re^{i\theta}) - 1 \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= -2i \int_{0}^{\pi}  \left( -\frac{a}{2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= a\pi i.
\end{align*}

---

*Addendum.* By the same technique, we have

> **Proposition.** For each $a < -1$ and $\gamma > 0$, set $\beta = -\gamma+\sqrt{\gamma^2-a-1}$. Then we have
>
> $$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \left( \sqrt{f(x)} - \sqrt{f(-x)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}x = i \pi a + 4i \int_{0}^{\beta} t \left( \frac{-a}{t^2+2\gamma t+1}-1 \right)^{1/2} \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

The extra integral on the right-hand side comes from part of the branch cut $[0,i\beta]$ lying inside the upper half plane. And Mathematica seems to suggest that this integral reduces to elliptic integral.

Comment: You have to consider the zeros too though, not just the poles. If $a = -2, \, \gamma = 1$, then $g(z) = \sqrt {z^2 + 2 i z + 1}/(z + i)$, which has a branch point at $z = i (\sqrt 2 - 1)$. There isn't a branch of $g$ which is analytic in the upper half-plane.

Comment: @Maxim, Thank you, that is a good point. I originally formulated my answer for $a>-1$ where we are indeed free of both poles and zeros, and I will soon fix my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I am really ashamed that I did not check my claim for $a<-1$ (in my problem the question arised from the condition $|a|\le1$ was satisfied).  Is it possible to give a closed form expression for the integral in the case $a<-1$?

Comment: @user, I updated my answer accordingly. It seems that when $a < -1$ and the principal square root is used, the integral involves an extra integral term which I guess is written in terms of elliptic functions. So I am skeptical that it has any nice closed form.

Comment: Could you please comment on the following. Your method works due to using the integrand $z(g(z)-1)$ instead of $z(g(z)-g(-z))$. Indeed if one uses the latter, one ends up with $$\frac{R^2e^{2i\theta} \left( f(Re^{i\theta}) - f(-Re^{i\theta}) \right)}{g(Re^{i\theta}) +g(-Re^{i\theta}) },$$ which would give the correct result only if $g(z)+g(-z)\sim\dfrac{4i\gamma}z$ for large $z$ in the upper complex half-plane. Is it correct?

Comment: @user, The point of using $z(g(z)-1)$ instead of $z(g(z) - g(-z))$ is that $g(-z)$ is not analytic (and even not well-defined) on the upper half plane.

Comment: I would assume that using an appropriate cut in the complex plane it should be possible to define the function almost everywhere, should not it?

Comment: @user, That is true. But since we are utilizing the 'contour shifting technique' (recall that we are continuously deforming the line segment $[-R, R]$ to the arc $-\Gamma_R$.), the presence of branch cut is never good for us. It will introduce an extra contour integral arising from wrapping the branch cut, and this will certainly complicate the computation.